# Error while using Toast.makeToast in non activity class using kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, android-toast

I am building a chatting application in android using Kotlin. I want to long press on a message to copy it on the clipboard. This function is working fine but I am unable to show a toast due to some error. Here is my code.

```
class ChatFromItem(val text: String, val user: User): Item<ViewHolder>() {
override fun bind(viewHolder: ViewHolder, position: Int) {
    viewHolder.itemView.textView_from_row.text = text
    viewHolder.itemView.textView_from_row.setOnLongClickListener {
        Toast.makeText(this, "Message copied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
        val clipboard = it.context.getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE) as ClipboardManager
        val myClip = ClipData.newPlainText("label", text)
        clipboard.primaryClip = myClip
        true
    }

    val uri = user.profileImageUrl
    val target = viewHolder.itemView.imageView_chat_from_row
    Picasso.get().load(uri).into(target)
}

override fun getLayout(): Int {
    return R.layout.chat_from_row
}
```

}

Some people might get confused as of why there is a 'true' written at the very bottom of .setOnLongClickListener. Without the toast statement the rest of the code is working fine. I have tested it many times. 
I am including an image containing the error message that android studio is showing me.

[image]

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please post the full code of this ChatLogActivity

Comment: "This function is working fine but I am unable to show a toast due to some error" -- the IDE is giving you the error, saying that you need to pass a `Context` as the first parameter, and `this` is not a `Context`.

Comment: try `Toast.makeText(viewHolder.itemView.context, "Message copied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you are using `setOnLongClickListener { /* your code here */ }` in kotlin it is the equivlent to:

`setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {public boolean onLongClick(View v){ /* your code here */ }});` in java

Therefore when you do this:

```
 viewHolder.itemView.textView_from_row.setOnLongClickListener {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Message copied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
    ....
 }
```

It's the equivalent to this:

```
setOnLongClickListener(new OnLongClickListener() {
     @Override
     public boolean onLongClick(View v) {

          Toast.makeText(this, "Message copied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()


     }
});
```

As you can see the `this` in the code above is not of the type `Context` it's of the type `OnLongClickListener`!

You can find a context using the view that you have:

```
 Toast.makeText(viewHolder.itemView.context, "Message copied", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass context or get it from a view, like itemView.context.

Comment: No problem! I'm glad i could help, feel free to mark this as the correct answer if it helped you.